# Wrapping JS file in function, and assigning that function to a variable

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I've been reading about wrapping JS files in functions to call them on load, etc. I also was looking at namespaces and how to avoid collisions with functions/objects/variables of the same name. What improvements can be made? I know the code works, I'm more concerned with best practices for wrapping JS files and using namespaces.

```
// codereview.js:
var codeReview = (function() {
    // basically "private" function? Will there be a collision with jQuery here?
    function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    // "public" functions
    return {
        fizzbuzz: function() {
            var newhtml = '';
            var output = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                    output = "FizzBuzz";
                } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    output = "Fizz";
                } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    output = "Buzz";
                } else {
                    output = i;
                }
                newhtml += output + "<br />";
            }
            $('fizzbuzz-output').innerHTML = newhtml;
        },
        email: function() {
            var first = "test@em";
            var last = "ail.com";
            var email = first + last;
            $('my_email').innerHTML = email;
        }
    }
})();
```

Both of the "public" functions would be called via `codeReview.fizzbuzz()` or `codeReview.email()`

Also, `codeReview.email()` is basically just to click and reveal my email address. I did it this way thinking it couldn't get scraped, is that accurate or did I just come up with a super complicated way to display an email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a organizing perspective you are doing fine, in essence you used the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). I would just advise you to consider placing `'use strict';` in the beginning of your function.

As you probably figured out, `$` does not collide with `jQuery`. Though, for this piece of code I would not create a one line function if you are only going to call that function once.

For the email thing, I think it might fool a number of scrapers, I'd keep it.

For fizzbuzz, while your code is working, I think the goal is to use a minimum amount of modulo statements, your code could be written with fewer modulo statements..

My counter suggestion is very close to your code:

```
// codereview.js:
var codeReview = (function() {

    // "public" functions
    return {
        fizzbuzz: function() {
            var output, i;
            for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                output = '';
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    output = 'Fizz';
                }
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                  output += 'Buzz';
                }
                output = output || i;
                console.log(output);
            }
        },
        email: function() {
            var first = 'test@em';
            var last = 'ail.com';
            var email = first + last;
            return document.getElementById('my_email').innerHTML = email;
        }
    }
})();

codeReview.fizzbuzz();
```

[This was an interesting read](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest), which provided an alternative inner loop which is more code review friendly:

```
            for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                if (i % 15 == 0) {
                    output = 'FizzBuzz';
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    output = 'Fizz';
                }
                else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                  output += 'Buzz';
                }
                else{
                  output = i;
                }
                console.log(output);
            }
```

Comment: Thank! Is my labeling of "private" and "public" functions accurate? Private functions and public methods? I'm not sure which is appropriate.

Comment: I tend to use `//private` and `//exposed`, since you might be exporting more than just functions in the future.